# How do we observe on a sql query when the query returns a non empty resultSet

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, observable

If we have a Java process that fires a query as `select name from Person where id = '123'`, and another process which inserts the record with the id `123`, how can the first process be notified when the record has been inserted?

Comment: @juergend how can we implement this, without having the first process poll with a wait time, to see if the record has been inserted.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You insert a record and want to know the generated ID for it?

Comment: Let's say my query doesn't return a value, as the record is not yet inserted. So usually what we do is, we do a exponential wait with a max retry count. Is there anyway to listen that the record has been inserted, without writing this exponential wait and retry

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to have a look into Database Change Notification:

> Database Change Notification is a feature that enables client
> applications to register queries with the database and receive
> notifications in response to DML or DDL changes on the objects
> associated with the queries. The notifications are published by the
> database when the DML or DDL transaction commits.
>
> During registration, the application specifies a notification handler
> and associates a set of interesting queries with the notification
> handler. A notification handler can be either a server side PL/SQL
> procedure or a client side C callback. Registrations are created on
> all objects referenced during the execution of the queries. The
> notification handler is invoked when a transaction subsequently
> changes any of the registered objects and commits.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_dcn.htm#BGBBHGAH